# When talking about below assembly, where would a FPGA's netlist fall?

Tags: assembly, fpga

When talking about below assembly, where weould a FPGA's netlist fall?

```
C -> assembly -> machine code -> microcode -> circuits -> atoms -> ?
```

Would it be machine code, microcode, or circuits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely to the circuits, as it simulates the hardware.